# Checking bottom of css using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a sort of feed with quotes and I want to reset a quote if it drops below a certain level on the screen.

```
function MoveDown(speed) {

            $('#QuoteOne').animate({
                  bottom: '-=100'
                }, speed);

            $('#QuoteTwo').animate({
                  bottom: '-=100'
                }, speed);

            $('#QuoteThree').animate({
                  bottom: '-=100'
                }, speed);

            $('#QuoteFour').animate({
                  bottom: '-=100'
                }, speed);

            console.log($('#QuoteOne').css("bottom"));  

            if($('#QuoteOne').css("bottom") == '-400px' )
            {   
                $('#QuoteOne').animate({
                  bottom: '= 0'
                }, speed);
            }
        }
```

The console log says -400px, but I cant get it to move back to the top. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, that code will execute before your animation has finished. If you want that code to execute after the animation, add it as a callback on your `#QuoteOne` element's `animate` function:

```
$('#QuoteOne').animate({
  bottom: '-=100'
}, speed, function() {
  if ( $(this).css("bottom") == "-400px" )
    ...
});
```

Then change `bottom: '= 0'` to `bottom: 0`.

```
$('#QuoteOne').animate({
  bottom: 0
}, speed);
```

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Can you tell me why the '-=' works but the '=' doesn't?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg I'm unable to answer that. It's probably because jQuery doesn't handle just `=n`, whereas `+=` and `-=` are valid mathematical operators in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm having difficulty chaining these. I need the three quote blocks to move down together, then the bottom-most one to fade in at the top. Your code fixes that, but only for one quote div.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg you can combine selectors with commas: `$('#QuoteOne, #QuoteTwo, ...').animate(...);`

Comment: Can you tell me why my fiddle looks wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/yfa4pj3m/#&togetherjs=2jjwHbiM7Q

Comment: The position:relative was causing a mess. Thanks for all the help!